# Couldn't draw rectangle,from user input parameters at runtime

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am trying to get 4 integer parameters from JTextFields in the method `paint(Graphics g)` I am parsing the user input to integer and then i am trying to parse it to the method `g.drawRect (x1, y1, x2, y2); , but when i run the app i get no rectangle at all.Here is the code:

On button click:

```
btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            Figure();
        }
    });


 public void paint(Graphics g) {

     int x1 = Integer.parseInt(textField.getText().toString());
     int y1 = Integer.parseInt(textField_1.getText().toString());
     int x2 = Integer.parseInt(textField_2.getText().toString());
     int y2 = Integer.parseInt(textField_3.getText().toString());


        g.drawRect (x1, y1, x2, y2);  
      }

 private void Figure()
 {
     JFrame window = new JFrame();
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setBounds(30, 30, 300, 300);
        window.getContentPane().add(new Form());
        window.setVisible(true);
 }
```

Thanks in advise !

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently. 3) *"I am trying to get 4 integer parameters from JTextFields"* For the sake of the user, offer them 4 `JSpinner` components using 4 spinner number models.

Comment: Okay, you seem to be coding by magic (writing some code and hoping by magic it works...I should know, I do it often enough ;P).  Start by taking a look at [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) for more details about how painting in Swing actual works